# Find several maximum dates in same group using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, time-series

I'm working with time series data in python pyspark. I'd have a situation like this:

```
name    value    date
Anna      5     1/2020
Anna      6     2/2020
Eve       1     1/2020
Eve       1     2/2020
Anna      2     6/2020
```

In an ideal case, we'd know the value of Anna and Eve for every month. Anna has reports for Month 1 and 2, but not 3,4,5. I want to find the maximum month of each "subgroup" of consecutive reports for every name. The desire output is thus:

```
name    date
Anna    2/2020
Anna    6/2020
Eve     2/2020
```

I've tried tinkering around with window functions and using first() after a max(), but I've not been successful.

Any hints or solutions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the rows where the next row is more than one month from the current row, or where the next row does not exist (i.e. this row is the last row for that name)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

lead_date = F.lead(F.col('date')).over(Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy('date'))
df = df.withColumn('end',
    (lead_date > F.add_months(F.col('date'), 1)) |
    lead_date.isNull()
)
df = df.filter('end = true').drop('end')
```

Comment: This appends 'end' = true to all the rows. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. What is the column type of 'date'? I tested with a column of type `date`

Comment: It worked! I had set it to be a date but apparently when I saved the table it had saved it as strings so I had to re-convert. Thanks!